# CircularpageIndicator appearing in top how to keep it in bottom

Tags: android

I am using viewpager indicator along with navigation drawer and I'm getting an error.  I got it working before integrating but after integrating this with navigation drawer I am getting error.  I've searched the net and found about relative layout is best but still, I am getting an error with it.  I have seen that for using pageviewer indicator Drawerlayout is root.  Please correct me if I am wrong.  Thanks

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

   <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    /> 
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

Comment: Put the VPI along the `ViewPager` not inside it.

Comment: the circularPageIndicator is like any other view ... you can place it wherever you want , so one approach is to place them both in a relativeLayout and give the circularPageIdicator the property  "alignParentBottom"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

   <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:layout_below="@id/pager"
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
```

and then in your code add the following

```
    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);


    mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
```